# ActionBar showAsAction="always" not working

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionBar and NavigationDrawer. I'm add onCreateOptionMenu() on ActionBar. Menu item showAction="always" but not working.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/information"
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Bilgi"/>
</menu>
```

Activity code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.infomenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

my_styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleColor" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is my manifets:
manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".util.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/eru"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".login"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".bildirimDetay"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
    </application>
```

Help me.

Comment: What's your problem actually? Does it never show up ? Or not showing in another activity ?

Comment: It is shown as "never." (Listed)

Comment: Can you please show your manifest file please?

Comment: Thanks for the co-operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mention java code in onCreateOptionsMenu()**

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.clear();
    menu.add(Menu.FIRST, R.id.System_log, 4, "LOGOUT");

    String get_api_key = new Database_for_Api_key(Activity_Drawer_Dashboard.this).getApi_key();
        MenuItem item =
                menu.add(Menu.FIRST, R.id.dashboard_nodifycation, 3, "NOTIFICATION");
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How can I add icon instead of item text?

Comment: item.setIcon(R.drawable.white_nodification);

Answer (score 0):

Remove theme from manifest application and you are good to go:

Replace:

```
<application
        android:name=".util.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/eru"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

With:

```
<application
        android:name=".util.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/eru"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Set AppBaseTheme to parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, Are you sure your xml file is named as infomenu ? you have written here as menu.xml ? (Just Checking)

Comment: Yes, It was. I changed it later. For the first time I get such an error.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If this doesn't work you may try out the Toolbar. It is super customizable and now recomended by Google for Material design,

Comment: thank u for all answers. I will look for other solutions.